# Windows function returning duplicated rank, how can I return only one of them?

Tags: sql, join, window-functions

Here's the thing, I have two tables, one contains the customer purchase of a specific product, let's call it Product X, and the another table with all purchases from customers. I was trying to get the product each customer purchased before buying Product X.

Here's what I did:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*,
FROM
    (SELECT 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.customer_ID, t1.purchase_date
                      ORDER BY t2.purchase_date DESC) AS my_rank,
         t1.customer_ID,
         t1.purchase_date,    -- purchase of product X
         t2.purchase_date AS last_product_purchase_date,
         t2.product_name AS last_product_name
     FROM 
         purchase_product_X AS t1
     LEFT JOIN 
         all_purchases AS t2 ON t2.purchase_date < t1.purchase_date
                             AND t2.customer_ID = t1.customer_ID) T
WHERE 
    my_rank = 1 OR myrank IS NULL -- filter the last purchase before product X 
                                    -- or leave it null in case it didn't exist
```

However, it looks like some customers had more than one product bought in the same date. I don't want to duplicate the original table, so I need to bring only one row, even though it is a random selection among all products. How can I do this? Get only the first appearance among all rows with rank = 1 that will appear.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you’re running: mysql, oracle, postgresql…?

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like some customers had more than one product bought in the same date. I don't want to duplicate the original table.

Switching from `rank` to `row_number` guarantees no ties - so no duplicates. However, in absence of a column to break the tie, the result is non-deterministic (typically, not guaranteed repeatable).

I would still recommend adding more columns in the `order by` clause of the window functions to make for a stable results - eg if the primary key of your table is `pk`:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY t1.customer_ID, t1.purchase_date
    ORDER BY t2.purchase_date DESC, t2.pk
)
```

Comment: FWIW I looks like dupes are complete dupes, so no need to break ties here?